# Apache password request on every file save

Tags: apache, mamp

I'm sure this has been asked, but i couldn't find the answer. I apologize- its  my first question on stack.

I'm using MAMP (free) on Lion. I have changed the location of htdocs to my Sites/ folder. I'm using port 8888 for apache. I DO NOT get asked password on startup or shutdown which is fine, BUT I DO get asked for my password on every file save. This has become an issue when using CODEKIT to compile my SASS to CSS. **How would I turn these prompts off?** I'm not looking to change permissions of individual folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a glitch with my mac. Just in case others come across this post- 
To fix it, I had to repair my user permissions using this tutorial: http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/15/repair-user-permissions-in-mac-os-x-lion/

It seems to have done the trick, not sure how it got messed up in the first place.